# Display expanded quickactions buttons on related lists on 3 region split layout

Tags: lightning, page-layout, related-list, quickaction

I have a 3 region split layout where there's more than enough room for a "New" Button which is hiding collapsed under the arrow but it's auto collapsed with this kind of layout and I can't find a way to display it.

See attached picture for example on related Medlemskap, Cases and Opportunities. I don't want the quick actions collapsed, any way to achieve this?

[image: example of related lists]